# What is the controversial 8th grade algebra mentioned on this answer?

Tags: curriculum

An [answer](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/17889/766) on this site mentions that it would be more appropriate to criticize

> Efforts to force kids to take algebra at lower and lower ages, such as attempts in California to make all kids take algebra in 8th grade.

What exactly is this "algebra" that they have to learn?

As another person in the comments, I don't find starting algebra at the eight grade outrageous, but maybe the topics behind the general term are a bit different.

I've had what's called "algebra" here since grade 7. We had equation and inequality solving, single-argument functions, linear functions, monomials and polynomials. And in grade 8 we got to factoring polynomials (*short multiplication* formulae) and solving quadratic equations.

What do people in the US normally have at that age? And what is in the California attempt?

Comment: I found this article, stating the exact opposite (that California is moving away from Algebra in grade 8): https://www.latimes.com/local/education/la-me-edu-algebra-segregation-20160323-snap-htmlstory.html  Maybe ask the poster of that answer directly for sources or an explanation?

Comment: Also depending on who you ask, solving simple linear equations (e.g. $5x + 3 = 7$, solve for $x$) can already be considered "algebra".

Comment: @Dirk indeed, that's why I am asking. And I pinged the person. I decided it's better to split this off in a question of it's own instead of dragging on and on in the comments that unfourtunately tend to get deleted on this site.

Comment: is that not algebra? It's simplistic, but I've always thought the inclusion of variables is the beginning of algebra.

Comment: @bob0the0mighty maybe you can provide some insight to the "What do people in the US normally have at that age?" part? It appears from your profile you might have experienced that. No variables at all in the 7th and 8th grade?

Comment: @Džuris, I went through algebra classes in 7th and 8th grade. It's been about 20 years, but I remember learning to solve simple equations of the type above as well as using similar tools during science classes in the same grades. I was responding to Dirk, where they imply that simple equations aren't algebra.

Comment: Džuris, the short answer is that American secondary education is way below most European and Asian school systems. If an 8-grader reads on a level of a 2-grader, which happens very often, you cannot teach them algebra or physics or even geography or proper history — kids simply cannot read and comprehend. Asian kids routinely used to take algebra in 7th or even in 6th grade, and when California decided to move algebra to 9th grade, it caused an uproar among Asian parents.

Comment: "I've had algebra **here** since ..." where is here?

Comment: @jonathanjo Latvia. I cited the curriculum as it is and has been for the past decades.

Comment: @Džuris: 2018 PISA mathematics results for 15-year-olds: OECD mean 489. Latvia 496. USA 478. See http://www.oecd.org/pisa/publications/PISA2018_CN_LVA.pdf and http://www.oecd.org/pisa/publications/PISA2018_CN_USA.pdf . See also http://www.oecd.org/pisa/PISA%202018%20Insights%20and%20Interpretations%20FINAL%20PDF.pdf

Comment: Latvia apparently does not currently participate in TIMSS for mathematics: https://nces.ed.gov/timss/countries_advanced.asp

Comment: @shoover, what do you want to imply with these links and scores?

Comment: @RustyCore Just illustrating your point to Džuris about American secondary education compared to the rest of the world, particularly Latvia, where Džuris is.