# are there Evidence-Based Justifications for Mandatory Mathematics Education in School Curricula?

Tags: value, value-of-mathematics-education

I am currently working on a project to secure funding from our city council for our university. Participants from various academic disciplines are invited to contribute. The primary challenge I'm facing is convincing policymakers and public administrators of the value of investing in mathematics education. While it is generally acknowledged that mathematics is an indispensable part of education, I aim to go beyond this common understanding by presenting evidence-based justifications.

In this context, I've observed some movements, notably in certain U.S. states, advocating for the removal of mathematics from school curricula, citing the subject's potential to cause (math anxiety) trauma among students.

My question to the community is: Are there any references or studies that discuss the importance of mandating mathematics education for children and adolescents? Specifically, I am looking for research that highlights the cognitive, developmental, and practical benefits of learning mathematics, which could effectively counter the arguments for its removal from school curricula.

Any insights or guidance on where to find such studies would be greatly appreciated.

there is already a  related question posted in this forum: [Justifications for: Why learn mathematics?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/8052/justifications-for-why-learn-mathematics)

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: wouldn't a serious study of "research that highlights the cognitive, developmental, and practical benefits of learning mathematics," require an experimental group (being monitored on) not receiving mathematics instruction for (quite) some period of time? this seems unlikely to happen, specially considering the 'WEIRD problem/bias'

Comment: Maybe identify the math skills needed in common applications, e.g. basic statistics, graphs, spreadsheets, personal and small business finances, designing simple systems.

Comment: @fedja  work also as a teacher of msth teachers an I think the question is a good source of reflection fot duture math teachers ... this is my second target.

Comment: I recommend that you read the thread https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/20962/response-to-students-who-say-this-is-not-important before shaping your defense of mandatory math education. There are many valid and not entirely obvious points made there (which you are free to agree or disagree with, but the existence of which you should be aware of before engaging in any related argument).

Comment: There is plenty of empirical evidence - nations in which mathematics education is compulsory and universal have better standards of living than nations in which it is not. There are all sorts of things wrong with what I just wrote, but it gets to a point I wish to make - what is relevant socially are the benefits at the population level rather than at the individual level.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about using the adjective "mandatory" just for mathematics, as most other subjects that are in school curricula are also mandatory. But you can refer to findings in the book titled:

*[Does Mathematical Study Develop Logical Thinking?](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1786340682)*

[Here](https://ro.uow.edu.au/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=&httpsredir=1&article=1480&context=eispapers1#:%7E:text=This%20book%20is%20recommended.,is%20clear%20and%20well%20written.) and [here](https://maa.org/press/maa-reviews/does-mathematical-study-develop-logical-thinking-testing-the-theory-of-formal-discipline) are two different reviews of this book, if you want to know what is in the book.

Comment: Thanks. another book more or less aligned with this is "The Disorder of Mathematics Education"(https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-34006-7)